# How to replace nested or multilevel array's selector by a single string

Tags: php, arrays, string, drupal, syntax

I'm trying to replace multilevel array selectors by a single string in PHP. The code below that I've tried is running in PHP 7.2.

**1.**

```php
$nested_array_selectors = '"my_array"]["my_key"]["my_elemnt"';
var_dump($my_instance->my_object[$nested_array_selectors]);
```

**2.**

```php
$nested_array_selectors = 'my_array"]["my_key"]["my_elemnt';
var_dump($my_instance->my_object["$nested_array_selectors"]);
```

**3.**

```php
$nested_array_selectors = '["my_array"]["my_key"]["my_elemnt"]';
var_dump($my_instance->my_object$nested_array_selectors);
```

I expect that $nested_array_selectors could work as `$my_instance->my_object["my_array"]["my_key"]["my_element"];` but 
**1** and **2** return "null" and **3** gets a `Parse error` (of course).

Is it actually impossible or could someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
$selectors = ["my_array","my_key","my_elemnt"];

$data = (array)$my_instance->my_object;

foreach($selectors as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($data[$k])){
        $data = $data[$k]; //reduce data by 1 level
    }else{
       $data = false;
       break;
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Basically each time you loop over a "selector" that exists in the array, you reduce the array by 1 level so for example if we start with this

```
$data = ['foo'=>['bar'=>['baz'=>1]]];
$selectors = ["foo","bar","baz"];

foreach($selectors as $v){
    print_r($data);
    if(isset($data[$v])){
        $data = $data[$v]; //reduce data by 1 level
    }else{
       $data = false;
       break;
    }
}
echo "\n---------- Final ------------\n";
print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => 1
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [baz] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [baz] => 1
)

---------- Final ------------
1
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e387e3312271afc6ff3d54a3da53741eca2c8bdb)

You can see "illustrated" above how we can drill down to the element we want.  Each `array` above is the state of `$data` before reducing it by that selectors level.  So the one after that shows the results of reducing it.  So the first array is before applying `"foo"` the second is after that but before `"bar"` etc...

If you want to use a string for `$selectors` like with commas or whatever, it's a simple matter of using `explode()` or `preg_split()` to break that string on some delimiter into an array.  For example:

```
 $selectors = "foo.bar.baz";
 $selectors = explode(".", $selectors ); //["foo","bar","baz"]
 //...
```

**PS**  I would have used real data had it been provided, but as it is this is the only way for me to test it an explain it.

Also, this is obviously a good candidate to make a function out of:

```
function transverseWithKeys(array $array, $keys, $default=null, $glue='.'){
   if(!is_array($keys)) $keys = explode($glue,$keys);

   foreach($keys as $v){
       if(isset($array[$v])){
           $array= $array[$v]; //reduce data by 1 level
       }else{
           return $default;
       }
   }
   return $array;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix.Thanks for your patient explanation.
I have a little problem for understanding your code, It's my fault.
Easier done than said for programming, I'll try it.

Comment: `I have a little problem for understanding your code` - if you can put it into words feel free to ask and I will try to explain it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work because you are trying to convert a variable into PHP code. PHP does not know this is your intention and is not executing that code.

PHP does have an `eval()` construct that enables you to do this.

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

The [PHP manual for eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) explains more.

> Evaluate a string as PHP code

In your case, the following code will work.

```
$nested_array_selectors = '["my_array"]["my_key"]["my_elemnt"]';
eval('var_dump($my_instance->my_object' . $nested_array_selectors . ')');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
BTW, In my case I need :
`$my_instance->my_object["my_array"]["my_key"]["my_element"];`
to `$my_instance->my_object["$some_var"]`.
Or any other else that could shorten or integrate the multipart parameters.

Comment: E.Thank you.This is acturally closest answer, but 'eval' is too dangerous.